# How to count beyond $2\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, pi

How do I count beyond $2\pi$ if I make another one full circle? Mainly I want to know what will come in place of $\pi/6$, $\pi/2$ and so on.

Comment: What happens for `pi/2`,'5pi/6` etc..

Comment: Do exactly the same thing.  Add them to $2\pi$.

Comment: Should I add to 2pi until I reach 4pi? I mean complete one full circle.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to $2\pi$ by finding a common denominator, for example
$$2\pi + \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{12\pi}{6} + \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{13\pi}{6}.$$